# Am I using withTracker correctly? I am getting an error relating to imports/exports but cannot figure out the issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

So I am upgrading an old project to an updated version of react and decided to replace the createContainer for meteor-react-data with the withTracker method. I believe I have gotten the syntax correct but I get an error that seems to be about me not importing or exporting correctly.

I have tried many different combinations of export and import but nothing seems to work so I'm not sure if I'm just making a stupid error.

SurveysPage file

```
import React from "react";
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { withTracker } from "meteor/react-meteor-data";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import orderBy from "lodash/orderBy";
import includes from "lodash/includes";
import capitalize from "lodash/capitalize";
import Folders from "/imports/api/folders/folders";
import Survey, { SurveysWithFirstResponse } from "/imports/api/surveys/surveys";
import SurveysList from "./surveys-list";
import Header from "/imports/ui/layouts/header";
import Main from "/imports/ui/layouts/main";
import Loader from "/imports/ui/loader";

export class SurveysPage extends React.Component {
    -- SurveysPage code
    }
}

const SurveysPageContainer = withTracker((props) => {
    const subs = [
        Meteor.subscribe("folders"),
        Meteor.subscribe("all-surveys"),
        Meteor.subscribe("surveys-with-first-response")
    ];

    const loading = subs.some((sub) => !sub.ready());
    const folders = Folders.find().fetch();
    const surveys = Survey.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch();
    const surveysWithFirstResponse = SurveysWithFirstResponse.find().fetch();

    let detailedFolders = [];
    // TODO (mix) refactor the surveys-with-first-response publication to do this join
    if (!loading) {
        detailedFolders = folders.map((folder) => {
            const surveysInFolder = surveys.filter((s) =>
                includes(folder.surveys, s.origin.id)
            );
            const decoratedSurveys = surveysInFolder.map((s) => {
                const surveyObj = surveysWithFirstResponse.find(
                    (surveyObj) => surveyObj.originId === s.origin.id
                );
                if (surveyObj && surveyObj.responseId)
                    s.responseId = surveyObj.responseId;
                return s;
            });

            const contents = orderBy(decoratedSurveys, "title");

            return Object.assign({}, folder, { contents });
        });
    }

    return { loading, folders: detailedFolders, surveys };
})(SurveysPage);

export default SurveysPageContainer;
```

Routes.jsx file

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import BasicLayout from "./layouts/basic-layout";
import SurveysPageContainer from "/imports/ui/surveys/surveys-page";
import ResponsesPage from "/imports/ui/responses/responses-page";
import ResponsePage from "/imports/ui/response/response-page";
import AssignmentPage from "/imports/ui/assignment/assignment-page";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory();

const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <Route path="/" component={BasicLayout} />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={SurveysPageContainer} />
                <Route path="survey/:surveyId" component={ResponsesPage} />
                <Route path="survey/:surveyId/assignment" component={AssignmentPage} />
                <Route
                    path="/survey/:surveyId/response/:responseId"
                    component={ResponsePage}
                />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default Routes;
```

Errors are as follows:

```
backend.js:6 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    in Unknown (created by SurveysPage)
    in div (created by SurveysPage)
    in SurveysPage (created by ReactMeteorDataComponent)
    in ReactMeteorDataComponent (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (created by Routes)
    in Switch (created by Routes)
    in Router (created by Routes)
    in Routes
    in div
```

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=95dbfaa7286d1ad0d61289dcea7b3a5605866b43:28717:34
    at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=95dbfaa7286d1ad0d61289dcea7b3a5605866b43:28720:13)
    at createFiberFromElement (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=95dbfaa7286d1ad0d61289dcea7b3a5605866b43:28741:15)
    at createChild (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=95dbfaa7286d1ad0d61289dcea7b3a5605866b43:18691:28)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=95dbfaa7286d1ad0d61289dcea7b3a5605866b43:18942:25)
    at reconcileChildFibers (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=95dbfaa7286d1ad0d61289dcea7b3a5605866b43:19279:14)
    at reconcileChildren (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=95dbfaa7286d1ad0d61289dcea7b3a5605866b43:21372:28)
    at updateHostComponent (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=95dbfaa7286d1ad0d61289dcea7b3a5605866b43:21851:3)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=95dbfaa7286d1ad0d61289dcea7b3a5605866b43:23191:14)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=95dbfaa7286d1ad0d61289dcea7b3a5605866b43:5028:14)
```

```
backend.js:6 The above error occurred in the <div> component:
    in div
    in Unknown (created by SurveysPage)
    in div (created by SurveysPage)
    in SurveysPage (created by ReactMeteorDataComponent)
    in ReactMeteorDataComponent (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (created by Routes)
    in Switch (created by Routes)
    in Router (created by Routes)
    in Routes
    in div
```

I suspect the problem is coming from the either the exporting of the withTracker on SurveysPage file or the importing on the Routes file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: issue came from importing  from react-router instead of react-router-dom in the Header component.